# Mongoose Model.update with dynamic field name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'mtrying to pass field name as variable , here is what I tried but it's not working :

```
var update={};
update[req.body.field]=req.body.value;
Model.update(
    {"email":req.user.email},
    {$set:{update}},
    function (err,success) {
        if(err) return handleError(err);
    }
)
```

req.body.field contains the name of the field defined in the Model schema and req.body.value is the value I want to update with

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need update to be in braces, since it is already an object. Try:

```
var update={};
update[req.body.field]=req.body.value;
Model.update(
    {"email":req.user.email},
    {$set:update},
    function (err,success) {
        if(err) return handleError(err);
    }
)
```

Comment: thank you so much Arun Ghosh for  your quick answer :-)

Comment: @user3711521  : dont forget to make this answer as resolved if it is useful.. We need more reputation for our freind Arun Ghosh

Comment: I didn't forget , I was waiting for the 15 minutes period to accept the answer