# How can I reduce the size of MongoDB code?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I need some help with organising this mess...
I was wandering if I could put all of this to functions, but I don't really know how.

```
if(args[0] == 'add'){
    if(roleType == 'join') add = await roleModel.updateOne({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$addToSet: {joinRoles: role}});
    else if(roleType == 'member') add = await roleModel.updateOne({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$addToSet: {memberRoles: role}})
    else if(roleType == 'mute') add = await roleModel.updateOne({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$addToSet: {muteRoles: role}})
    else return error02 = sendError02(this.usage);
}
else if(args[0] == 'remove'){
    if(roleType == 'join') remove = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$pull: {joinRoles: role}});
    else if(roleType == 'member') remove = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$pull: {memberRoles: role}});
    else if(roleType == 'mute') remove = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$pull: {muteRoles: role}});
    else return error02 = sendError02(this.usage);
}
else if(args[0] == 'reset'){
    if(!roleType) reset = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$unset: {joinRoles: '', memberRoles: '', muteRoles: ''}});
    else if(roleType == 'join') reset = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$unset: {joinRoles: ''}});
    else if(roleType == 'member') reset = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$unset: {memberRoles: ''}});
    else if(roleType == 'mute') reset = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, {$unset: {muteRoles: ''}});
}
```

Comment: Does (this)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548467/mongoose-model-update-with-dynamic-field-name] help you? Not functions exactly but dynamic fields in the query.

Comment: You are performing many different actions based on many different business rules.  To abstract this further and make the code more dense would probably make it difficult to read and understand by someone other than yourself.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks Wernfried Domscheit, I figured it out. I decided to try second code, but I had a little issue with "r" so I changed slightly the first part. That's how it worked for me:

```
let operation = {};
let types = ['join', 'member', 'mute']
for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++){
    if (types[i] == roleType){
    operation[roleType + "Roles"] = role;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do for example

```
var action;
var value = role;
if (args[0] == 'add') {
   action= "$addToSet";
} else if (args[0] == 'remove') {
   action= "$pull";    
} else if (args[0] == 'reset') {
   action= "$unset";
}
var operation = {};
for (let r in ["join", "member" ,"mute"]) {
   if(!roleType || r == roleType) operation[r + "Roles"] = value;
}     
var update = {};   
update[action] = operation;
reset = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({serverID: message.guild.id}, update);
```

Or

```
var operation = {};
for (let r in ["join", "member", "mute"]) {
   if (!roleType || r == roleType) operation[r + "Roles"] = role;
   // The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.
}

if (args[0] == 'add') {
   add = await roleModel.updateOne({ serverID: message.guild.id }, { $addToSet: operation });
} else if (args[0] == 'remove') {
   remove = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({ serverID: message.guild.id }, { $pull: operation });
} else if (args[0] == 'reset') {
   reset = await roleModel.findOneAndUpdate({ serverID: message.guild.id }, { $unset: operation });
}
```

Comment: There's one slight problem, "$addToSet" does not work in "findOneAndUpdate". But thanks for answering! I'll try it with "updateOne" instead

Comment: But you should get an idea how it  could look like.

Comment: This code is much harder to read compared to the original post.

Comment: Sure, but the question was not how to make it eayser to read. The question was: how to make it smaller?